# Why is storage cheaper than a memory?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Let's consider the following completely useless code (tested in Remix):

```
// solium-disable linebreak-style
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract
{
    struct TestVars
    {
        uint8 a;
        uint64 b;
        uint64 c;
    }
    
    TestVars private vals;
    
    constructor()
    {
        vals.a = 5;
        vals.b = 6;
        vals.c = 7;
    }
    
    function readValsStorage()
        external 
    {
        TestVars storage v = vals;
        uint a = v.a;
        uint b = v.b;
        uint c = v.c;
    }
    
    function readValsMemory()
        external 
    {
        TestVars memory v = vals;
        uint a = v.a;
        uint b = v.b;
        uint c = v.c;
    }
}
```

The thing we are into is gas cost. It wonders me why storage is cheaper.
I have read that each read from the contract storage costs gas. Also if you pack data into struct it behaves as one field unless you exceed the total size over 2^256.

So now my thougts come: if I read a, b, c from storage it will read 3 fields, so it will cause triple gas cost. It should be cheaper to read the entire struct to the memory as one field and grab variables.

But the result was opposite - the storage is cheaper. Why?

Answer (score 6):

Possibly a kind soul with more knowledge of v8 compiler optimization will chime in. This will be a general observation.

> storage is cheaper. Why?

That's a misleading conclusion because you read from storage in both cases.

```
TestVars storage v = vals;
```

```
TestVars memory v = vals;
```

What you do with it (left side) differs. In the `storage` case, you set a storage pointer to the `slot` where `vals` values can be found and *nothing else has happened*, yet.

In the `memory` case, you have copied the struct values from the storage location to `v`, in memory. This is *more work* than the first case.

As you carry on with the assignments to `uint a, b, c` you are copying from storage (for the first time), or from memory (again).

The assignments to storage (SSTORE) in the constructor are the most expensive operations in the contract, by a wide margin, followed by the SLOAD operations but both variations of your test read the same region.

You can see a little bit of a difference with this effort:

```
    function readValsMemory()
        external 
    {
        TestVars memory vals2 = TestVars ({
          a: 5,
          b: 6,
          c: 7
        });
        uint a = vals2.a;
        uint b = vals2.b;
        uint c = vals2.c;
    }
```

It is cheaper overall because it doesn't touch storage. The difference might not seem tremendous but keep in mind that it sets before it gets and still wins.

Hope it helps.